# Unable to use a wildcard in map

Tags: scala

I wonder, why doesn't this work due to the error

```
object ws1 {
 class MyClass(a: Long)
 val biList = List(BigInt(1), BigInt(2))
 val mcList = biList map { new MyClass(_.longValue) }        // error
 //val mcList = biList map { x => new MyClass(x.longValue) } // ok
}
```

of

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.longValue)
```

or more precisely

```
type mismatch: found ws1.MyClass, required scala.math.BigInt => ?
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.longValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `_` placeholder syntax for quick anonymous functions really only works in very simple cases. Your error explains what's going on here:

> missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.longValue)

So what happened was that this

```
val mcList = biList map { new MyClass(_.longValue) }
```

got expanded to this

```
val mcList = biList map { new MyClass(x => x.longValue) }
```

The lambda got created right where you put the `_`, rather than what you wanted as the whole curly-brace-enclosed portion. You'll just have to add the 3 extra characters (and some optional whitespace) if you want this to work the way you're expecting:

```
val mcList = biList map { x => new MyClass(x.longValue) }
```

Comment: why does this work `val someMap = parseData.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]]
      val result = someMap map { new MyClass(_) }`?